# Filtering fields in RFC_READ_TABLE with SAP JCo

Tags: java, sap-basis, jco

I am attempting to write a simple java utility that extracts data from SAP into a MySQL database, using JCo. I have understood the JCo documentation and tried out the relevant examples mentioned in [SAP help portal](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm),  I am able to retrieve data from Table and insert into MySQL DB.

What I would like to have is a facility to filter data in following two ways :

1. I would like to fetch only the required fields.
2. I would like to fetch rows only if the value of the a particular field matches certain pattern.

After doing some research I didn't find any way to specify query parameters so that it retrieves only the filtered data, it basically queries all the fields from a Table, I think I will have to filter out the data that I don't want in my java-client layer. Please let me know if I am missing out something here.

Here is a code example :

```
public static void readTables() throws JCoException, IOException {

    final JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager
            .getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME2);
    final JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction(
            "RFC_READ_TABLE");

    function.getImportParameterList().setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "DD02L");
    function.getImportParameterList().setValue("DELIMITER", ",");

    if (function == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BAPI RFC_READ_TABLE not found in SAP.");
    }

    try {
        function.execute(destination);
    } catch (final AbapException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return;
    }

    final JCoTable codes = function.getTableParameterList().getTable(
            "FIELDS");
    String header = "SN";
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.getNumRows(); i++) {
        codes.setRow(i);
        header += "," + codes.getString("FIELDNAME");
    }
    final FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("out.csv");
    outFile.write(header + "\n");
    final JCoTable rows = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("DATA");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.getNumRows(); i++) {
        rows.setRow(i);
        outFile.write(i + "," + rows.getString("WA") + "\n");
        outFile.flush();
    }
    outFile.close();

}
```

This method tries to read a table where SAP stores meta data or data dictionary and writes the output to a csv file. This works fine but takes 30-40 secs and returns around 4 hundred thousand records with 32 columns. My intention was to ask if there is a way I can restrict my query to return only a particular field, instead of reading all the fields and discarding them in the client layer.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a complete sample of the code that is not working.

Comment: I've tried examples mentioned in [SAP help portal](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm) and explored the API details, where I didn't find a way to filter data.

Comment: This is not a complete code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine :

```
JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");
table.appendRow();
table.setValue("FIELDNAME", "TABNAME");
table.appendRow();
table.setValue("FIELDNAME", "TABCLASS");
```

Please check this [Thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3440919)

Thanks.